# Why isn't my LAN world working in Minecraft 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend and I wanted to play together on my singleplayer world opened to LAN but we couldn't.

It kept displaying this message endlessly, but no matter how many times we tried to restart the worlds, Minecraft, or the computers, we still couldn't find my LAN world.

> Scanning for games on your local network

We have both checked the most basic things (we are within the same network, we were playing on the same version (1.9) and our firewalls are allowing everything), we didn't have mods on, and we were each using a separate paid MC account.

I've searched around a little, and it seems like this is a very common problem for players on Minecraft 1.9 so I was just wondering if it was a problem with the new 1.9 update?

Comment: Did you try using Direct Connect?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "We had the same Internet"? There is only one Internet I know about. Also, Internet connection should be irrelevant for this, because LAN stands for Local Area Network, as in multiplayer *not* over the internet.

Comment: @Philipp I assume she means that they were connected to the same network.

Comment: What operating systems are you and your friend running?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Minecraft, and the two questions have different messages displayed on screen, so I'm not going to vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: For Mac users, I recommend trying this: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/320864/199492

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that I have had in the past. This is what I did to fix it, it only works on Windows:

1. Open Command Prompt. To do this, press Win+R and type 'cmd' and hit enter.
2. Type in 'ipconfig' into the console that pops up.
3. What you are looking for is your IPv4 address. Find the IPv4 which starts with 192.168, this is your LAN IP.
4. Finally, in Minecraft, click direct connect and type in the IPv4 address followed by : and the port it tells you when you open the world to LAN.

Hope this helped!